# I dont understand why my #include isnt purple how it supposed to be even though I downloaded the things im sure need to be downloaded

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snl1n.png)

I want to make sure why my #include isnt even purple even though I downloaded C/C++ and Coderunner. I also made sure that my mac has clang installed and up to date so I dont know what is going on.

Comment: Why would it need to be purple?

Comment: I would worry more if the code didn't compile and run.  Fancy colors can and should wait for later.

Comment: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) follow the link and make sure you have done all these things

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the color scheme of VSCode, you can easily change it as you like

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/colorization-cpp